# increasing session time in php

Tags: php

I am trying to increase the session time using the following code :

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 60*60*24*15);
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", 60*60*24*15);
session_set_cookie_params(60*60*24*15);
session_start();
```

But the session is expiring in an hr or so. I could not make changes in php.ini

Is there an alternative to increase session timeout without modifying the php.ini

Comment: Try using a string instead of an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can set php value in .htaccess

```
   php_value setting_name setting_value

eg

  php_value session.cookie_lifetime  60*60*24*15
```